# Can't fly my AR Drone autonomously using Libardrone Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, ar.drone

I really need you help in this issue. I'm trying to use libardrone.py to fly my AR Drone autonomously. Here is my code:

```
import libardrone
from time import sleep

drone = libardrone.ARDrone()

drone.takeoff()
sleep(7)


drone.land()
sleep(3)
drone.halt()
```

However, my drone will keep hovering after takeoff  and it will never try to land. I got the following error: (I'm using windows 8)

```
Reloaded modules: arnetwork, libardrone, arvideo
Please install psyco for better video decoding performance.
Unable to bind video decoding methods with psyco. Proceeding anyways, but video decoding will be slow!
Exception in thread Thread-28:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mariam\Anaconda3\envs\python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "arnetwork.py", line 105, in run
    inputready, outputready, exceptready = select.select([self.drone.video_pipe, self.drone.nav_pipe], [], [], 1)
error: (10038, 'An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket')
```

is there any updated libardrone??